# Issue with binarySort method not returning proper item

Tags: java, logic, binary-search

So, I am trying to get my binarySearch to work and it dos not return the proper search item. Anyone have an idea? It always returns close to the item though.I know the issue is specifically with the while loop in the binarySearch method.

```
public class Sort { 
    static int item;
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = new int[500];
        for (int c = 0; c < 500; c++){
            Random r = new Random();
            list[c] = r.nextInt(1000);  
        }
        int l = list.length; 
        System.out.print("Enter a search element: ");
        System.out.println();
        item = console.nextInt();
        insertionSort(list, l);
    }
    public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int l, 
            int searchItem){
        int first = 0;
        int last = l - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        while (first <= last && !found)
        {
            mid = (first + last) / 2;
            if (list[mid] == searchItem)
                found = true;
            else if (list[mid] > searchItem)
                last = mid - 1;
            else
                first = mid + 1;
        }
        if (found) 
            return mid;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public static void insertionSort(int[] list,  int l){
        int first, location;
        int temp;
        for (first = 1; first < l; first++){
            if (list[first] < list[first - 1]){
                temp = list[first];
                location = first;
                do {
                    list[location] = list[location - 1];
                    location--;
                }
                while(location > 0 && list[location - 1] > temp);
                list[location] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(binarySearch(list, l, item));   
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you tried to debug the code?

Comment: Tes. That is how I found out that the issue was in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return mid + 1 as index start from 0.

So if you have 1,2,3 element and if you try to find 2, it will return 1 as array[1] points to 2. So if you return 2 it will mean that you found the element at second location.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies here:

```
    if (found) 
        return mid;
```

Say you have an array with numbers {1,2,3,4,5}
According to the way array indices get assigned 1 will get the index of 0, 2 will get the index of 1 and so on.

when you try to search for 2 and you find it, the value of mid(according to the program) holds the index of value 2 in the array.  The index of 2 in the above array is 1. So instead of returning the index of 2, you just need to return the item itself.

```
     if (found) 
        return list[mid];
```

I would say better design would be to return true/false from the binary search routine to indicate whether the item was found or not.  The reason being you return 0 as the case where you never find the item in the array which becomes problematic if 0 is also included in the values to search.

If you were trying to return the index of item once found instead of the item itself, then your program functions as expected other than the case where it wasn't found - it should return something like an index of -1 and not 0(a valid index).

```
      else
        return 0;
```